# I want to make UseEndPoints in extension method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to use `UseEndPoints()` extension method in another project than the main API project.

But I get an error

> IApplicationBuilder doesn't have UseEndPoints in the same context

My api startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        ...
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMapHubs();   // this is my custom middleware
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

In other project I want to implement the `UseMapHubs()` extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void UseMapHubs(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => // this is the line that fire the error and what I understood from that error that it doesn't find the name space or library for useendpoint 
        {

        });
    }
}
```

My question is: which nuget package or library does `UseEndPoints` exist in?

Comment: `UseEndpoints` lives in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder`. See [official MS documentation on `UseEndpoints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutingapplicationbuilderextensions.useendpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder; still fire an error for missing library

Answer (score 0):

you can add manualy this package to you project file.

```
<ItemGroup>
     <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"  Version="5.0.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

now, you can use 'UseEndpoints' in IApplicationBuilder